# Websites renders off the viewport on mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a new website today: [www.domanage.co.il](http://www.domanage.co.il). When I view it on my PC everything looks good on all viewports sizes. When I try to view it on my iPad or my iPhone it seems like the website is somehow "inside" the right side of the viewport.

photo (using browserstack for photo, but has also been checked on iPad and iPhone):
[image]

I'm using Bootstrap as my main CSS which I'm overriding in my own CSS file which can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/7v0Y7Uim

Any ideas why it might happen?

Comment: Try removing 100% width on your body.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( I don't even know how to start debug this issue :/

Comment: Remove the rtl, test, if it stops doing this, then it's in the rtl code which then you can debugg it by going to the github issue area for that add on and seeing if others have had this problem. Since it's shifting to the right, it's my best guess.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer That actually solved it, but raised another problem that now it's not rtl. However, let me check the answer someone else suggested

Comment: add img-responsive on your images. add back in the rtl, does it still happen? Then go to the rtl github page and see about an answer.

Comment: If it's rtl, try this version: https://github.com/carasmo/bootstrap-rtl/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css, but keep a copy of the other, un-minify it and post another SO question after you've made your best effort to correct. I have not messed with RTL in about 5 months but I helped make this version.

Comment: The answer Steve Sanders suggested was right on spot. Thank you a lot! I would still like to understand why removing the `dir:rtl` made it also work.

Comment: No idea off hand. Curious though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some elements that are too wide to fit in their containers, which is causing the issue.

```
@media(max-width: 500px){
    .websites img, .applications img {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
    }
    .btn-fixed-size {
        width:150px;
    }
    .btn-vlg {
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
    .btn-fixed-size {
        width:145px;
    }
}
```

`.col-xs-6` (these elements' container) only has something like 120px of space for the content on a 320px wide viewport. You are trying to put a 150px wide element inside of a 120px wide container. As a rule of thumb, I try to avoid having fixed pixel-based widths in my CSS for a responsive site. For images, just set them to `max-width: 100%` and `height: auto` to allow them to automatically resize.

Comment: Yes, this would be the issue. bootstrap has a class called img-responsive, use it. Then it won't do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer solved the issue. Thank you for taking your time viewing my website and looking into my (messy?) code. Much appreciated!